# Class inheritance from different modules python

Tags: class, inheritance, python-3.x, module

I'm new to python and I have a hard time trying to figuring out how can I inherit from a class in an other module.

module: ~/foo.py

```
import bar

class foo:
    def test(self)
        print("this is a test")
```

module: ~/bar.py

```
class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().test()
```

As soon as bar is imported, I get this error message :

```
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[If you want to refer to a name in another module then you must import it.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

```
import foo

class bar(foo.foo):
   ...
```

Comment: I tried that already, it doesn't works... I get the same message.

Comment: Why are you importing `bar` in `foo`?